# How to mock a property (path.sep) in Jest

Tags: properties, mocking, jestjs

I need to test if a module works both under Windows and Linux. The module is resolving a path and depending on the OS the path contains a forward slash or backslash. It uses the `path.sep` to determine which slash to use. In my test case I want to test both OS's. My problem is I cannot figure out how to change the value of path.sep as it is a property and not a function.

Am I missing something? How can I mock the `path.sep` property? I hope someone can shred some light on this.

Comment: is something wrong with mocking whole `path` module?

Comment: Good question. The functionality is using other methods of path and I didn't feel like mocking that functionality too.

Comment: speaking in general it's typical for unit testing to mock dependencies completely. and jest does not allow to unmock module partially. consider complete mocking as a possible approach here.

Comment: Thx for the tip. What do you think of the approach described in the answer?

Comment: Just to be complete...you can call [`jest.requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) when creating a module mock to get access to the original module and return a mock that replaces only parts of it, but that isn't really necessary for a string value like this since it can just be modified (and restored if needed) directly.

Comment: Good to know. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working example:

code.js

```js
const path = require('path');

export const func = () => path.sep === '/' ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

code.test.js

```js
const path = require('path');
import { func } from './code';

test('func', () => {
  path.sep = '/';
  expect(func()).toBe('foo');  // Success!

  path.sep = '\\';
  expect(func()).toBe('bar');  // Success!
});
```

---

Looks like it also works if you use

```js
import path from 'path';
```

...but it doesn't work (at least in my environment) with

```js
import * as path from 'path';
```

(Since `path` isn't currently an ES6 module the transpiler has to do some work to make the ES6 import syntax work and `import * as path from 'path';` must get transpiled in a way that breaks the approach above.)

Comment: Thx for the quick respons. This is actually how I was doing it as a workaround :-) But this isn't uising the mock functionality of Jest. Is it?

Comment: `Jest` doesn't provide a way to mock a simple string export like this since it is so easy to just change to something else (and change back if needed). @nidkil

Comment: (Note that `jest.spyOn` provides a lot of helpful functionality around mocking functions...but ultimately is also just [changing a module property to something else](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/05b8382751b06c08113d81de757976740d4d32bf/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L1013))  @nidkil